# Program a mega2560 from a different Serial port

Tags: serial, bluetooth, bootloader, atmega2560

I want to be able to use my HC-05, currently on Serial3 to download code to on my 2560 from a connected android tablet. I'm currently running MegaCore, which has optiboot on it.

I've looked for examples of this and can't find one. Surely someone is doing this and the optiboot documentation says you can do it.

I am currently planning on downloading the hex file, but let me know if there's a better approach.

Thanks.

Comment: download from where over HC-05? what format? hex or bin? or you want to make a Serial upload with avrdude over HC-05 on Serial3? then you need the bootloader to listen at that Serial

Comment: @Juraj What format should I use? I was planning on bin, but what format to write to the flash? Download from a tablet in the field that has the internet connection. That's kind of what I'm asking. How do I get the bootloader to listen to Serial3?

Comment: you want to use InternalStorage of my ArduinoOTA library to store and apply the updated sketch binary?

Comment: @Juraj That would be great! Will that let me read from the Serial port?

Comment: the transport of the binary is on you. the only transport available in the library is receiving upload from the IDE. see the Advanced examples on how to use InternalStorage with alternative transport of the binary

Comment: @Juraj The example in ArduinoOTA?

Comment: yes, the examples in the Advanced section

Comment: @Juraj And I should be converting the hex file to bytes at two characters per byte, and then writing that directly to flash. Is that correct?

Comment: let the avr tools create the binary. https://github.com/jandrassy/ArduinoOTA/blob/master/extras/avr/platform.local.txt#L4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127472/discussion-between-thom-and-juraj).

Comment: you could write an answer

Comment: @Juraj Don't really have one yet. I'm currently using OTA libraries.